# Google chart does not refreshes

Tags: javascript, google-visualization

I draw a chart using the google chart api and it works fine. Then I have several options that allow the user to interactively change the configuration of the chart (like the time period shown etc). This is done through a boton and an ajax call back. And this part works fine when the user makes up to 10 changes but after the 10th it wouldn´t work anymore as the chart no longer gets refreshed.

Is there anything that I can do about this?
many thanks

The function to refresh the chart is as follows:

```
function doChart1() { 

    var chartdata =  {dialog.object}._data;

        var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(
         chartdata
        );

        var options = {
           chartArea:{left:50,top:10,bottom:30,width:"100%",height:"83%"},                                  
           lineWidth: 2,
           width:1150, height:270,
           areaopacity: 0            
        };

   var formatter = new google.visualization.NumberFormat(
      {negativeColor: 'red', negativeParens: true, pattern: '###,###.##'});
      formatter.format(data, 1);

        var chart = new          google.visualization.AreaChart(document.getElementById('Grafico_resumen_a'));
         chart.draw(data, options);           
}
```

Comment: Are you getting any errors in console? Are you sure the doChart1 function is running?

Comment: I get no errors and I believe that tha doChart1 function is working well because it is only after 8-10 changes in the configuration of the chart that it stops working.

Comment: Try doing a console.log(chartdata) to check if data is being updated